# Find location of your click on a video in android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, xamarin

Trying to add videos on a mobile android platform but need to trigger events to based on the location of the video click. Which platform is the best to build this? Xamarin,Unity or Android Studio

Comment: Is your question about how to implement or which platform is best for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [setOnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener(android.view.View.OnTouchListener)) for your VideoView you can find out which position clicked:

```
  videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            float x;
            float y;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        motionEvent.getY();
                        motionEvent.getX();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Above code can be used in `Android-studio` same method exist in `Unity`[[here]](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html)and `Xamarin`[[here]](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/gestures/detect_a_touch/).

Comment: What's the difference to use of the idea?

Comment: It's really depends what you want to implement. In case of native android app use android studio, If you need multiplatform app use xamarin and if you need game engine use Unity.